# No puedo seleccionar un archivo.csv cuando utilizo Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android-studio, csv, android-intent

necesito ayuda estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación de consultas, y necesito importar una base de datos a SQLite desde un archivo.csv. Y estoy intentando usar `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` y todo va bien hasta el momento de querer abrir el archivo. El archivo aparece en gris como DESHABILITADO y no permite seleccionarlo.

```
//Buscar y abrir el archivo.csv
private void AbrirArchivo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/csv");
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}

//Recibe el archivo.csv
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            String path = uri.getPath();
            Log.e("Ruta del archivo",path);
            // Hacer algo con la ruta del archivo aquí
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Esto es lo que sucede]

Tambien he intentado con `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` pero tampoco me funciona.

```
Intent fileintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
fileintent.setType("text/csv");
try {
startActivityForResult(fileintent, requestcode);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Comment: En donde no permite seleccionarlo?

Comment: En la imagen se ve el intent del explorador de archivos de android, y el archivo que quiero seleccionar con extencion .csv esta como "deshabilitado"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debería funcionar con el Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT y Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE, el código quedaría así:

```
private void AbrirArchivo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/csv");
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Esto es lo mismo que se realiza, cuál es la diferencia?

Comment: El caso en el que comenta que añadio el Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT no le puso el intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE) y creo que es por ese motivo que no le funciona.

Comment: ya comento que esto lo realizó inicialmente.

Comment: ya lo solucione, en setType use "text/*" y con eso se soluciono. muchas gracias